# Sonar refuses to analize multimodule project

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have upgraded from Sonar 5.3 to 6.2 and a project X is giving me some weird errors at the sonar stage of the jenkins job (altough build finishes as STABLE).

The project is a standard multimodule maven java project.

Entering the project dashboard a single message appears on screen:

> "No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available
>   section is the configuration."

But in the upper-right corner the red "FAILED" tag shows up. That leads to the Background tasks of the project and there is the failed task with this error log:

> The project "com.foo:bar-submodule-1" is already defined in SonarQube
>   but not as a module of project "com.foo:bar". If you really want to
>   stop directly analysing project "com.foo:bar-submodule-1", please
>   first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of
>   project "com.foo:bar"

I do not want to delete the project and lose the historical data.

So the question is: How can i add a project Y (that is a submodule of project X but Sonar does not recognize it) as a submodule of project X?

**EDIT 1**

The parent project is the only one that has been analyzed through jenkins jobs.

Comment: you can add new names to the modules and sub modules in sonar-project.properties file and re run the analysis.

Comment: Do you confirm that you've been analysing _com.foo:bar-submodule-1_ since a while as a standalone project ? (even though it's a submodule of a bigger project). Output of _api/components/show?key=com.foo:bar-submodule-1_ could help give more context.

Comment: Output of api/components/show?key=: {"component":{"id":"AVXZ1QXRLUlRa7_XO26T","key":"com.foo::bar-submodule-1","name":":Bar Submodule1","qualifier":"TRK"},"ancestors":[]}

Comment: @lakshman If its necessary i will do it, i was thinking why sonar lost track of the submodules and if there was a way to rewire them without adding any files to the project

Comment: I suggested an alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that Sonar can't figure out your submodules, but the root issue is that there is another project/module with the same name conflicting with the project you are analyzing now. It happens, for example, when you extract a submodule as a standalone library and moves it as a root project and try to analyse the new project. Since it is a new project, but sometime in the past you had another project/module with the exact same name, it won't be able to finish the process. I have found three ways to fix this:

1. Delete the old project, if it is possible
   This is a option that I use when I have analysed mistakenly new projects (with wrong parameters for example) or when I am migrating servers and still have some wrong configuration in place. You can do this in the project's Configuration/Administration menu, ['Delete project'](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings#ProjectSettings-DeletingaProject).
2. Rename the old projects keys
   This is my default option, since usually what I want is just keep the old analyses data for old submodules that we are moving to other projects or promoting to root modules. You can do this in the project's Configuration/Administration menu, ['Update key' option](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings#ProjectSettings-UpdatingProjectKey).
3. Updating your current project's keys
   This option I use when the submodules conflict with other valid submodules (It can happen when you have different teams creating small libraries that happen to have the same keys). You can do this in two steps. First you need to update your project's keys following the option 2. The next step is to go to your project and update the modules and submodules names using the key sonar.moduleKey. The default value for this is : similar to sonar.projectKey, as [especified here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-ProjectConfiguration). Following these steps you won't lose all your records and old analyses.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Option 2 did the trick. I've renamed the submodules listed in the error page to *_old. But is not a rewire as i was hoping as i just ended with 2 projects of the same code but with different key. I'm gonna wait if someone finds a solution in the way i was thinking and then accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @JoseJuanCalderonViedma you can go to the Measures menu and search for projects and submodules which contains the key "com.foo:bar-submodule-1". It should return all the modules which contains this key, probably more than one in this case and one within a project with a key different from "com.foo:bar". After that you can apply some of the option I mentioned before.

Comment: @JoseJuanCalderonViedma Other thing you can try is, in the Configuration > Projects (Sonar 5.6), search for potential projects that could contains the duplicated submodule, if you find it you will be able to rename or delete it too. It is harder to do, but I have found 'lost' projects here before and solved similar problems as yours.